# Is the fundamental group of a maximal subfactor always $\mathbb{R}_{+}^{*}$?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras, subfactors, planar-algebras

The **fundamental group** $\mathcal{F}(N \subset M)$ of a unital inclusion of II$_{1}$ factors $N \subset M$ is defined as :   $\mathcal{F}(N \subset M) =\{t >0 \ | \ (N \subset M)^{t} \simeq (N \subset M) \} $   (see [BNP](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0604460.pdf))

**Examples**:

- It's $\mathbb{R}_{+}^{*}$ for every finite index finite depth irreducible  hyperfinite subfactor (see [BNP, p262])
- It's trivial for uncountably many subfactors of the form $R^{\mathbb{Z}_{2}} \subset R⋊\mathbb{Z}_{3}$ ([BNP])

A subfactor $N \subset M $ is **maximal** if it admits no non-trivial intermediate subfactors $N \subset P \subset M $.

**Examples**:

- Every $2$-supertransitive subfactors: $A_{n}$-subfactor, Haagerup subfactor...
- Every group-subgroup subfactor $(R^{G} \subset R^{H})$ such that $(H \subset G)$ is a maximal subgroup
  (i.e. $\pi_{H}(G)$ is a [primitive permutation group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_permutation_group) with $\pi_{H} : G \to S_{X}$ canonical for $X = G/H$).

> Is the fundamental group of a maximal subfactor always
> $\mathbb{R}_{+}^{*}$ ?

**Remark** : For being relevant, we need to restrict to factors with full fundamental group. And for being reasonable, we can start by inclusion of hyperfinite II$_{1}$ factors. Next, we could enlarge to every factors with full fundamental group  (for example $L(\mathbb{F}_{\infty})$).

---

*Reference*

[BNP] Dietmar Bisch, Remus Nicoara, Sorin Popa, Continuous families of hyperfinite subfactors with the same standard invariant, International Journal of MathematicsVol. 18, No. 03, pp. 255-267 (2007).

Comment: I highly doubt this is known. I don't have much intuition about what being a maximal subfactor gives you, but I think the only results about fundamental groups of subfactors is what you give above. (Well almost, by Popa's work any amenable subfactor, not just finite depth, has full fundamental group, and as mention in the BNP article you cite it is true for any stable subfactor). As far as results where it is not all of $\mathbb{R}^+$, I think that the BNP examples are all that is known.

Comment: Intuitively, a maximal subfactor is a kind of *quantum generalization* of a prime number, because $R^{G} \subset R$ is maximal iff $G = \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ with $p$ a prime number.

Comment: I had read about *stable subfactor* in the BNP: << i.e. splits a common copy of the hyperfinite $II_{1}$ factor $R$ >>, but I don't understand what does it mean.

Comment: Stable means the that $P\subset Q\simeq P\otimes\mathcal{R}\subset Q\otimes \mathcal{R}$.

Comment: You're just asking about subfactors of the hyperfinite II_1 here?  Or do you want to let M be any factor with full fundamental group?

Comment: @NoahSnyder: a priori it's for any factor with full fundamental group, but maybe the restriction to inclusion of hyperfinite $II_{1}$ factor is more reasonable. I'm not sure the fundamental group is invariant under some natural equivalences of subfactor (see this [post](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/136411/whats-the-natural-equivalence-of-subfactors-in-general)). Of course, if $\mathcal{F}(M)$ is not full, $\mathcal{F}(N\subset M)$ can't be full, and a priori, there is maximal (irreducible) subfactor of $M$. So your comment shows that this post need to be improve, but it's not clear how.

Comment: @NoahSnyder: after Guionnet-Jones-Schlyaktenko, it's not clear for me if it is relevant to consider inclusion of factors without a full fundamental group. For example, I don't know the subfactor theory for a factor $N$ with $\mathcal{F}(N) = \{ 1 \}$, but a priori it's very restrictive.

Comment: You can get any finite depth subfactor you want as a subfactor of a factor with trivial fundamental group, see http://arxiv.org/abs/1112.4088

Comment: @NoahSnyder : thank you for this link. The fundamental group of such subfactors is trivial. So, this confirms that it is not invariant under natural equivalence of subfactor. In my opinion, we should choose one natural equivalence relation $\sim$ of subfactor (see some examples [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/136411/whats-the-natural-equivalence-of-subfactors-in-general/136424#136424)) and define another fundamental group, by replacing the isomorphism  $\simeq$ by $\sim$ : $\mathcal{F}_{\sim}(N \subset M)=\{t>0 : (N \subset M)^{t} \sim (N \subset M) \}$, it would be more relevant.

Comment: @NoahSnyder : note that after some comments of Owen Sizemore [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/136411/whats-the-natural-equivalence-of-subfactors-in-general/136424#136424), uncountably many non-isomorphic subfactor in the Bisch-Nicoara-Popa paper, are equivalent, and their fundamental group $\mathcal{F}_{\sim}$ is full (while it's trivial for $\mathcal{F}$). Maybe this would change for another choice of $\sim$...